# MATLAB: String Manipulation and File Input/Output

Tags: matlab, file-io

Ok so I have a data file similar to this one containing the names and weights of people:

```
Darby George          166.2
Helen Dee            143.5
Giovanni Lupa    192.4
Cat Donovan       215.1
```

Im supposed to read the script into strings one line at a time, save the weight into a vector, and print each person's name in the form 'last,first' followed by the weight:

```
George, Darby’s weight is 166.20 lbs.
Dee, Helen’s weight is 143.50 lbs.
Lupa, Giovanni’s weight is 192.40 lbs.
Donovan, Cat’s weight is 215.10 lbs.
```

This is my code:

```
fid = fopen('patwts.dat');
if fid == -1
    disp('File open not successful')
else
    while feof(fid) == 0
    % Read one line into a string variable
    aline = fgetl(fid);
    %Save vector and fprintf here
    strtok(aline,' ')=[first last num];
    fprintf('%s %s %3.2f',last,first,num)
    mat=['%3.2f %3.2f %3.2f %3.2f %3.2f %3.2f 3.2f %3.2f %3.2f %3.2f']
    end
    closeresult = fclose(fid);
    if closeresult == 0
        disp('File close successful')
    else
        disp('File close not successful')
    end
end
fprinf('The average weight is $sum(%3.2f)/2 lbs', num)
```

I'm having problems with the `strtok` function.

I don't know how to format the string to read `'last, first' weight`.

Answer (score 0):

`[token, remain] = strtok(aline,' ')` will return the first token "Darby" and the remain of the line. I don't think it is what you are looking for.
I would suggest to use `strsplit(aline, ' ')`, it will return a cell containing all the tokens and you would need to get each "first, last, num" by doing a for loop (for example)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `strtok`.  I would use [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) instead and split it based on spaces.  Replace your `strtok` call with `strsplit`.  Also, declare an empty vector... call it `mean_vec` that will store the weights as you read them in.  Once you get to the end of the file, you can calculate the average weight after.

As such, try something like this:

```
fid = fopen('patwts.dat');
mean_vec = []; %// Add here to store weights per line
if fid == -1
    disp('File open not successful')
else
    while feof(fid) == 0
    % Read one line into a string variable
    aline = fgetl(fid);

    %// Change -  Split up string by spaces
    C = strsplit(aline, ' ');

    %// Change - Print out the information        
    fprintf('%s, %s''s weight is %s lbs\n', C{2}, C{1}, C{3});

    %// Change - Save weight to vector
    mean_vec = [mean_vec; str2double(C{3})];        
    end

    closeresult = fclose(fid);
    if closeresult == 0
        disp('File close successful')
    else
        disp('File close not successful')
    end
end
%// Change - Use mean, not sum
fprintf('The average weight is %f lbs\n', mean(mean_vec));
```

What's important is that every single part of the line is a **string**.  Therefore, if you want to get the actual number that's at the end of the line, you need to convert it to a number with [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html).  Once I ran the above code, including the fact that I made a file called `patwts.dat` and put in your example data in it, I get this:

```
George, Darby's weight is 166.2 lbs
Dee, Helen's weight is 143.5 lbs
Lupa, Giovanni's weight is 192.4 lbs
Donovan, Cat's weight is 215.1 lbs
File close successful
The average weight is 179.300000 lbs
```